# How to get customer address with address id

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, shipping-address, address

Can i get customer address like picture below with **address id**? If i can, how should i do it?

[image: customer shipping address]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the formatted address using `address id` with below code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper,
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->_addressConfig = $addressConfig;
    $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
}

public function getFormattedAddress($addressId)
{
    try {
        $addressObject = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
        /** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\RendererInterface $renderer */
        $renderer = $this->_addressConfig->getFormatByCode('html')->getRenderer();
        return $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($addressObject));
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i place that code to block?

Comment: Yes you can add the code in block

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing showed when i call the function in phtml

Comment: Doesn't the `----` will fail in the code? Is `----` a legit code element in PHP?

Comment: I have updated the code and tested. please check. @max: I have used this to just make reference to add this code with existing construct code `----`

Comment: what  `- - - -` you mean?

Comment: Ignore that Use the updated code. it will work fine

Comment: Rather use `//` comments instead of code-breaking fragments. :)

Comment: Can i get address without first and last name and telephone

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order as follows wherever you want to invoke this information add following in the Constructor if not already being used.

protected $checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {

```
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}


$order = $session->getLastRealOrder();
$orderdata = $order->getData();
$shipping_address_id = $orderdata['shipping_address_ID'];
```

> This address is the final shipping address selected during payment
>   stage of the checkout process.